# Unable to retrieve correct target value in a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I am building a simple shopping cart app and using Stimulus JS to handle the interaction between the Rails views and Javascript logic.

In the Cart page, I am displaying the product by looping through them in the UI as:

```
<% @curr_cart.items.each do |item| %>

     <span id="test" data-target="cart.count">

        <%= item.quantity %>

     </span>
```

I am trying to add a 'delete' functionality that removes items from the cart. My removal logic works fine but I am unable to update the quantity of the right item. Every time I remove a product, only the **first** item's quantity gets decremented.

This is how I'm updating:

`this.countTarget.innerHTML = Number(this.countTarget.innerHTML)- 1;`

Tried using values and data attributes but no luck :frowning:

Spent most of today, trying to figure this out but wasn't able to. Any idea or suggestions on how this can be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code and description you have posted I suppose you are using one instance of the stimulus controller for all of the cart items. Something like this:

```
<div data-controller="cart-items">
  <% @curr_cart.items.each do |item| %>
    <span id="test" data-target="cart.count">
      <%= item.quantity %>
    </span>
    ...
    other fields
    ...
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This approach has one problem, you have to figure out which item you are trying to edit and change the correct fields. From what I understand items should not be dependent on each other. I would suggest to you to use one stimulus controller instance per line:

```
<% @curr_cart.items.each do |item| %>
  <div data-controller="cart-item">
    <span id="test" data-target="cart.count">
      <%= item.quantity %>
    </span>
    ...
    other fields
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now every line is bound to itself in JS controller, you don't have to search for a particular line in `countTargets` array, you have only one `countTarget` in each line. This should solve your problem. Disadvantage is that lines cannot communicate with each other, but you could achieve it by another stimulus controller if you need that.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing. However, would like to know if there are any issues with having/creating multiple controller instances (for instance if this was being done for a large list of items) ?

Comment: I don't think there should be any issues, Stimulus was created with this usage in mind, one controller can be used many times on one page and it should work fine.